# Await, catch and assign to variables - fetch/xhr responses node js, puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to get page data, but unfortunately there is no way to make all requests.

Therefore, the question arose - How, after opening the site, get from all Fetch / XHR requests with the name v2 JSON contained in their responses?
In this case, as I understand it, need to use waiting.

It is not possible to peep into the request and the body and repeat a similar request, since the body uses code that is generated randomly each time - therefore this is not an option, it was in connection with this that it became necessary to simply display all json responses from requests with names v2.

I am attaching a screenshot and my code, I beg you - point me in the right direction, I will be grateful for any help!

```
// puppeteer-extra is a drop-in replacement for puppeteer,
// it augments the installed puppeteer with plugin functionality
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";

// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'

export async function ProductAPI() {
    try {
        puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('here goes link for website');
        const pdata = await page.content() // this just prints HTML
        console.log(pdata)
        browser.close();
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}(ProductAPI())
```

link for image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR6T1.png

I know that the code I wrote just returns html. I'm just trying to figure out how to get the data I need, I googled for a very long time, but could not find the answer I needed.

> **It is very important that the execution is on node js (javscript) and  it doesn’t matter if it’s a puppeteer or something else.**

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5314

Comment: Happened! But how to print not one but several with the specified address?

Comment: In the example it's comparing the adress to a string. In your case you have to check if the adress CONTAINS a string. Example : request.url().includes(yourstring)

Comment: how to choose responses only from xhr/fetch tab? i'm getting now all responses from whole network tab...?

Comment: If you also have some images for example that has 'v2' in their urls, you'll probably want to make another condition for extensions, and also you can get headers and check type of content,,,

Comment: in v2 i have only json, no images or html, how i can filter it?

Comment: I wrote it in the comment, you'll have to check if the url has the word 'v2' or not. I wrote an example eariler in comments

Answer (score 1):

This works!

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'

async function SomeFunction () {
        puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        page.on('response', async (response) => {
            if(response.url().includes('write_link_here')){
            console.log('XHR response received');
            const HTMLdata = await response.text()
            console.log(HTMLdata)
            
        };});

        await page.goto('some_website_link');}
```